# Cannot allocate memory при установке пакета через composer в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer

У меня возникла ошибка в Laravel.

При установку данного пакета через composer в Laravel.

```
composer require uapixart/laravel-turbosms
```

У меня сразу появляется  такая ошибка.

```
mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Как можно исправить данную проблему.

Comment: php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer install

Comment: Нужно прописать консоль?

Comment: В [php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/configuration.file.php) можно поменять настройку memory_limit

Comment: Спасибо !!!!!!!

Comment: У меня стоить php memory_limit=-1, но она не работает.